# Simple Python chatbot in Replit

Tags: python, chatbot, replit

I'm a lawyer and (very) beginning programmer.  I'm at step 1 of learning to build a chatbot that can hopefully help me advise my clients someday.

I'm trying to follow this Medium post on how to build a simple python chatbot:
https://towardsdatascience.com/how-to-create-a-chatbot-with-python-deep-learning-in-less-than-an-hour-56a063bdfc44

Luckily I was able to import the author's GitHub repo to my Replit.
Author's GH: https://github.com/jerrytigerxu/Simple-Python-Chatbot
My Repl: https://replit.com/@AugieRakow/Simple-Python-Chatbot#chatbot_model.h5

But I can't quite get it to work.

I have 3 embarrassingly basic questions:

1. main.py.
   I didn't see a "main.py" file in the GH repo, so I imagine I need to add that. Is that correct?
2. code excerpts
   The author's Medium post includes code excerpts that appear to be importing various libraries etc. Should I copy all those code excerpts into main.py?
3. chatbot_model.h5
   The contents of the author's chatbot_model.h5 file on GH are appearing in my Replit with garbled red "NULNULNUL" text repeating line after line. Is that a corrupt file?  Is there an easy remedy?
   https://replit.com/@AugieRakow/Simple-Python-Chatbot#chatbot_model.h5

Any guidance is much appreciated!

Answer (score -1):

1. No, a `main.py` doesn't have any specific meaning, it's just conventional to name the "entry point" that name. Any other name can be used for an "entry point" too.
2. You probably need to use libraries shown in the tutorial, but you need to import them in those files where they are used.
3. It's probably just some value it can't decode to something that it could show you properly so it just substitutes it with that symbol, it's probably nothing, just an encoding thing or similar. Most certainly it shouldn't mean that the file is corrupt.